# Binding listener to a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap's list group to create a row of tabs. When someone clicks on an element in a table, it dynamically creates a new tab and appends it to that list group.

```
        var newtext = "#"+ticket+" - "+parele.find("td:nth-child(3) strong").html();
        var closebtn = $("<button>").addClass("close ml-2 mr-n2 newlyaddedclose").html("&times;");
        var newdiv = $("<div>").addClass("d-flex justify-content-between").append(newtext).append(closebtn);
        var newa = $("<a>").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-action").attr("data-toggle","list").attr("href","#ticket"+ticket).attr("id","ticket"+ticket+"-tab").append(newdiv);
        $("#ticketpanel").append(newa);
```

The problem I am having is the newly created close button. I need to bind a function that identifies when that is clicked to handle closing that tab, but it doesn't seem to be working. In my example here, I added the "newlyaddedclose" class to help identify the new element temporarily and I added the following code below to bind a function that is defined at the top of my script tag:

```
$(".newlyaddedclose").on("click",".close",closebtn).removeClass("newlyaddedclose");
```

This still doesn't work. When I inspect the close button element, console shows this error: Framework Event Listeners API Errors:
event listener's handler isn't a function or empt

Am I making this harder than it needs to be, or what am I doing wrong? I can simple put at the end of this element creation this:

```
$(".close").click(function() { ... });
```

But doing this starts to double up and triple up etc, those events on already created tabs.

EDIT:
Here is my entire block of script to clear up any confusion.

```
    $(function() {
  function closebtn() {
    alert("Close button clicked...");
  }
  $(".ticket-line").click(function() {
    var parele = $(this);
    var ticket = parele.data("tnum");
    // Check to see if ticket is already open in tabs
    if($("#ticket"+ticket).length == 0) {
        // Create tab on ticket panel
        var newtext = "#"+ticket+" - "+parele.find("td:nth-child(3) strong").html();
        var closebtn = $("<button>").addClass("close ml-2 mr-n2 newlyaddedclose").html("&times;");
        var newdiv = $("<div>").addClass("d-flex justify-content-between").append(newtext).append(closebtn);
        var newa = $("<a>").addClass("list-group-item list-group-item-action").attr("data-toggle","list").attr("href","#ticket"+ticket).attr("id","ticket"+ticket+"-tab").append(newdiv);
        $("#ticketpanel").append(newa);
        $(".newlyaddedclose").on("click",".close",closebtn).removeClass("newlyaddedclose");
        // Create DIV with content
        var newdata = $("<div>").addClass("tab-pane").attr("id","ticket"+ticket);
        $("#ticket-tabs").append(newdata);
        $("#ticket"+ticket+"-tab").tab("show");
    } else {
        // Ticket is already open, switch to it instead
        $("#ticket"+ticket+"-tab").tab("show");
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: .on("click",".close",closebtn) <--- um, you are saying the function to call is closeBtn.... but that is a button reference....

Comment: closebtn is a function I have defined elsewhere in my script tag. That's where I will build the handler when the closed buttons are pressed.

Comment: Well I assume it is being overwritten by the closeBtn you reference.... Impossible to tell with the code provided.

Comment: And there you go, with the edit you proved you have two variables with the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly stating you are binding a non function to the event listener. So the error is saying that `closeBtn` is not a function. Your code, you defined `closeBtn` as the button you are trying to attach the event too. So change `closeBtn` in the click event listener to the name of the function you are actually trying to call. If it is the same function name, rename something.

Your problem:

```js
var closeBtn = 1;
if (1===1) {
  var closeBtn = 2;
  console.log(closeBtn);
}
console.log(closeBtn);
```

It is unclear why you are selecting the element you just added. You can just attach the event when you create the button, no need to look up the element.

```
var closebtn = $("<button>")...
closeBtn.on("click", function (){
  console.log('clicked', closeBtn);
});
```

Or use event delegation so any element you add will trigger the function.

```
$("#ticketpanel").on("click", ".close", function () {
  const closeBtn = $(this);
  console.log('clicked', closeBtn);
});
```

Comment: I tried adding the .on("click" .... line to the variable where it is created too, but the outcome was the same either way.

Comment: because as I stated, you are using the same variable name.... closeBtn on the outside is overwritten by the closeBtn in the inside. Name your variables to what they are doing.

Comment: *facepalm* I kept overlooking that variable I made with the same name as the function. Changing that function name to something different and adding it to the variable where I create the button works. Thanks for pointing it out and showing the different ways to get this done!